# Unreal How to make my static mesh undestroyable in run-time unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I created unreal game and it have a option that can select objects that you need to place on the floor from a widget menu. And it also have a option to remove the objects that placed on the floor when pressed "R" key. My problem is when I place my tracer on the floor and press "R" it also remove the floor and then character start to falling down. So, anyone no how to remove only selected objects and not everything in the game.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create a new class (C++/Blueprint) for your 'destructible' static meshes. Then while tracing you could try to cast the object you're pointing at to newly created class and if casting is successful, destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use "Actor has tag", but then you'll need to add the tag on each individual actor you want to affect.

You can edit channels in the Project settings -> Collision, make a new channel specific to things you want to affect, and then change the collision settings on the actors and on the linetrace.